# python NameError: global name 'multiprocessing' is not defined

Tags: python, multiprocessing, nameerror

I am trying to convert my threaded code to multiprocessing code. but it is giving me error

```
    Name Error: global name 'multiprocessing' is not defined
```

Multiprocessing is installed and I imported it by

```
    from multiprocessing import *
```

Comment: Star imports are considered bad practice.

Comment: I dont know what you are referring to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your import, you will import everything inside the `multiprocessing` module. I assume that you are making a call that looks something like

```
multiprocessing.some_function()
```

but since you've imported everything *inside* `multiprocessing`, it will not be in your namespace. I recommend that you do `import multiprocessing` and use that as your point of entry to not clutter your namespace.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But now when I am running the code, it is using all   8 cores and my system is hanging. I added below line but it dint helped.        po = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

Comment: That's a completely different issue. I have very little experience with the multiprocessing module, but I suggest you research your problem (read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), [browse SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+multiprocessing)). If you're stuck after that you can consider posting a new question.